# Best control to use in display of a Tree view/Graph like structure

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, webforms

What is the best ASP.NET control to use when you want to display a tree like structure?

eg:

Back End

```
class Tree 
{
    int id
    string name
    List<Tree> childs
}
```

Front End (when i receive a list of Tree objects)

```
Menu1
    Item1
    Item2
    Item3
        SubItem1
Menu2
    Item4
    Item5
```

Comment: Isn't supposed a binary tree to have only two children? Maybe you meant "Treeview" ?

Comment: Do you need webforms or MVC?

Comment: @SteveB you are right... sorry about that

Comment: @SteveB Ok, but what's about actually `TreeView` one? Not sure if there are any other 'out of the box' ones for webforms.

Comment: @SteveB With TreeView I can have a non-clickable display of labels with diferent css styles for each level and without those ugly buttons? xD

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: the native TreeViewControl exposes a lot of features, that allow to customize it deeply. But reading your comment, you may create you own control that will produce a very simple html list (`<ul>` or `<ol>`), with nested list to produce the hierarchy. Then it will be easy to style using css.

Comment: @SteveB I would use nested list, but the thing is that i don't know how many levels the data will have. 3 levels = nested list (List>List>List) right?

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: that's the idea... Use recursion to render the lists

Comment: @SteveB But isn't that limiting? If i add a new level, it would have impact in the web component. Can you look at this question plz: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069162/nested-repeater-vs-treeview-vs-simple-html

Comment: @HélderGonçalves: not with recursion